# Can the  [big-o] ← [complexity] synonym suggestion be reversed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

So I intended to introduce the synonym [complexity](/questions/tagged/complexity) ← [big-o](/questions/tagged/big-o) but accidentally suggested  [big-o](/questions/tagged/big-o) ← [complexity](/questions/tagged/complexity).

The proposal hasn't received enough votes in either direction.  Is there a way to delete the first and suggest the reverse tag synonym?

Answer (score 4):

Since you were the creator, I went ahead and deleted the old suggested synonym.  You can go ahead and create the intended one now.